# how to disable alt+F4 for the application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I disable the use of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> application-wide for C# applications?

In my application, I have many WinForms and I want to disable the ability of closing the forms using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.  Users should be able to close the form using "X" of the form though.

Again this is not for just one form. I am looking for a way so <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is disabled for the entire application and will not work for any of the form. Is it possible?

Comment: You should ask yourself a question - why do you want to remove this standard way of closing dialogs? You're breaking convention and to do so needs a very good reason - check out the user experience stack exchange.

Comment: Wow the possible duplicate was an exact to the person who answered it and then suddenly deleted it.  Shady!

Comment: Wow and then editing it to : `I would recommend doing the following:`, @Daniel please stop copying and pasting answers from others whilst taking credit.  Mark the question closed as duplicate and find better things to do with your time.

Comment: I have an application where user can register a hotkey and once the hotkey is pressed the attached logic will be performed. Before we used to use a third party library where hotkey management was encapsulated inside the library. And user was able to use ALT+F4 as a valid hotkey. But now I am swapping this third party library with my own dll. Other hotkey functionality is done except this part where dont close the form on alt+f4 and let it be a valid hotkey. So, I have no choice except keeping the behavior same.

Comment: @MChicago - then use the "Possible duplicate" link posted by CodeIgnoto at the top of these comments.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate because it asks for a way to do this globally for the entire application rather than on a form-by-form basis.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek - The answer still is the same, you can implement this code in a global function / class and re-use it across all forms.

Comment: @JonH this is it not a duplicate question. Coz the other question resolves the issue for just one winform. What if I have 50 forms in one application. Should I implement this logic for all 50 forms? I was hoping for a solution where we can override WndProc and filter alt+F4 right there.

Comment: @MChicago - No you re-use the code across all your forms, implement once and re-use across your application.

Comment: @JonH: That wouldn't be very global if you had to write code in each form again and again. Maybe created a `Form` base class that includes that functionality, or perhaps enumerate the `Application.OpenForms` collection and attach this behavior dynamically. In any case I believe the *global* solution is worth an answer of its own, even if it's based on the existing answer linked above. The point of the question is **HOW** to reuse the code provided in the linked answer across all `Form`s, which ins't answered in that answer.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek - You are not rewriting the most important piece of the code, that is all the details that are found in the "duplicate" link of this post.

Comment: @JonH: The most important part of the code is the one that you don't know how to write, at least for the question asker. Please be respectful of *their* problem.

Comment: @JonH I see what you are saying. But I wanted to keep this behavior in the global key library that I have created instead of keeping the alt+f4 logic on the client application which uses the dll. Because in future there might be many trading applications which are going to use the global hotkey library that I have created.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek Thank you sir for understanding the real issue. For sure it is not duplicated.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek - `Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.` the nice thing about stackoverflow is you can vote to re-open.  Use what is there, if you believe you can help with the solution that to me is already there and requires a very little bit of effort than feel free to re-open and provide the solution.

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate question. I voted for re-open.

Comment: @JonH What I was expecting was a solution where the alt+F4 can be detected and filtered in an AppDomain's message loop even before WinForm receives it. But before doing anything, I wanted to get expert's advice. Thanks JonH now "A man is going to learn how to catch a fish by himself (without stackoverflow)". I still believe that this is not a duplicate question but I will invest my energy finding a solution instead of wasting arguing on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MChicago - you can vote to re-open, I don't see an issue with that.

Comment: @MChicago: Please edit your question (and question title) to reflect the uniqueness of your question, and why it's not a duplicate (highlighting that the problems that needs solving is globalizing the functionality). Also include your muses about approaching the problem, it makes the question clearer and gives idea to people. Unfortunately I don't have a solution myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put something like this in the main startup method:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.AddMessageFilter(new AltF4Filter()); // Add a message filter
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    public class AltF4Filter : IMessageFilter
    {
        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
            if (m.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
            {
                bool alt = ((int)m.LParam & 0x20000000) != 0;
                if (alt && (m.WParam == new IntPtr((int)Keys.F4)))
                return true; // eat it!                
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution. What if the message is processed late (due to a delay) and `Control.ModifierKeys` no longer reports that `Ctrl` is pressed down (missed it)?

Comment: thanks for the solution. I was looking for something like this. By the way along with alt+F4, it also filters out alt+shift+F4. Just to let you know.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek - Hmm... I see we have a picky audience :-) I have updated my answer to use lParam's 29th bit instead of Control.ModifierKeys.

Comment: Hello @SimonMourier how can I disabled  CTRL-ALT-DEL, ALT-TAB and Start Menu  Thanks.

Comment: @DreamerXD - ask another question