# Unexplained OverflowException casting IntPtr representing screen-coordinate to Int32

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, wndproc

We have a WinForms AnyCPU application in which a vendor library control occasionally throws the following exception on a 64-bit user's box running multiple monitors:

```
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at VendorLibraryName.VendorControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I've looked at the vendor library control's WndProc handler, and the only bit of code that looks like it could produce an overflow is this (comments mine - this is decompiled):

```
switch (msg)
{
    case 132: // NCHITTEST 
    case 672: // NCMOUSEHOVER 

    // Technically dangerous: convert IntPtr to Int32 in a 64-bit process.
    // However, note that for these message codes, 
    // LParam represents a "packed" x and y screen-coordinate. 
    // Given my understanding of how this packing occurs, I can't think
    // of how to construct an LParam such that it would overflow an Int32.
    SomeMethod(x: (int)m.LParam & 65535, y: (int)m.LParam >> 16);

    // More code...
```

Here's the actual IL for the conversions and bit-twiddling:

```
IL_0092: ldarg.1
IL_0093: call instance native int [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Message::get_LParam()

// As far as I can tell, this is the only instruction on which overflow could occur
IL_0098: call int32 [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::op_Explicit(native int)

IL_009d: ldc.i4 65535
IL_00a2: and
IL_00a3: ldarg.1

// Same thing here...
IL_00a4: call instance native int [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Message::get_LParam()
IL_00a9: call int32 [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::op_Explicit(native int)

IL_00ae: ldc.i4.s 16
IL_00b0: shr
```

Clearly, this routine looks susceptible to overflow issues as there is a conversion of Message.LParam (an IntPtr) to Int32 in a 64-bit process. In fact, this routine is *wrong* in that it doesn't deal with negative coordinates correctly - it looks like an incorrect port of the windows GET_X_LPARAM and GET_Y_PARAM macros to C#.

*However*, I am unable to see how an LParam could be constructed for NCHITTEST / NCMOUSEHOVER which would, in practical terms, overflow the range of Int32. (I *think* the lower 16 bits consist of the *signed* 16-bit X coordinate and the remaining bits consist of the sign-extended 16-bit Y coordinate. Please correct me if am wrong as this might be a critical misunderstanding).

I am unable to reproduce the exception on my dev-box with many different monitor configurations and window positions.

**What screen-coordinates could actually result in an overflow here? Or is there any other way this block could result in an overflow?**

Comment: Even if you don't find out why the parameters overflow, blind conversion of IntPtr to Int32 is clearly a bug in the library. Microsoft just guarantees what's documented, it doesn't guarantee anything about the undocumented bits. You should contact the vendor for a bug fix

Comment: @Simon: That's true. This vendor hasn't been prompt with bug fixes in the past though; so I expect that to take time. Meanwhile, I want to identify what *exactly* triggers the exception in production so that we can instruct users on how to work around it. Medium term, we will probably put some workarounds in our application code. First though, I need a repro!

Comment: Hmmm...could it possibly have something to do with a virtual desktop size? Only thing I can think of that would proper overflow...

Comment: Just an idea: could you install a global IMessageFilter filter to avoid entering that function, or replace it? A bit like what's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898680/how-to-disable-altf4-for-the-application

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for that. I'm still at the stage where I want to be able to repro; but your suggestion does seem like a decent eventual workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key of your problems lies in "multiple monitors". [Multiple monitors can lead to negative coordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

From MSDN:

> Important  Do not use the LOWORD or HIWORD macros to extract the x-
>   and y- coordinates of the cursor position because these macros return
>   incorrect results on systems with multiple monitors. Systems with
>   multiple monitors can have negative x- and y- coordinates, and LOWORD
>   and HIWORD treat the coordinates as unsigned quantities.

Since on the CLR signed numbers are represented using [2-complements notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), negative numbers are represented as "big" unsigned numbers (those whose most significant bit is '1'); for example, -1 is 1111....1. Hence, the overflow when casting to a (signed) 32 bit integer.

EDIT: 
(disclaimer: I do not have multiple monitors, so some guesswork applies)
In short: my guess is that you have to generate a negative y coordinate.

Suppose the coordinates are (x: -1, y: -1)

As short numbers: x: 0xFFFF, y: 0xFFFF

Packed in a 32-bit number: 0xFFFF FFFF

Now, this is where guesswork is involved: there is NO sign extension to IntPtr (can you try it with the debugger? You will need a neg y coordinate). Therefore it becomes:

```
0x0000 0000 FFFF FFFF
```

Or 4294967295 Which is a number too big to cast it to Int32.

In general, any negative Y coordinate will be in the form

```
000.(32 Zeros)..001 ...(other 31 digits) .. 0
```

and should bring up the problem (have you tried stacking the monitors one above the other?)

Comment: I'm aware of the negative coordinates bug in the vendor routine (as I mentioned). However, none of my testing with negative coordinates (both x and y) cause any overflow exceptions - they cause incorrect interpretation of the coordinates. Could you give me any sample negative coordinates that would cause errors?

Comment: I think the error in the library is converting to int before applying the mask/shift. Let me think if there may be some extreme case where coordinates may result in extremely big numbers.. or if it can be concluded that no values can cause an overflow, and you have to look elsewhere...

Comment: I have added my (educated) guess, and provided an example

Comment: I did try simulate y coordinates (involved telling Windows that my monitor configuration involved vertical stacking), which is when I noticed the sign extension happening. Anyway, thanks for your efforts so far.

Comment: ..and so my guess was wrong :) Based on your check (the number is sign extended) I would say that an overflow is not possible:  Win32/BCL/Winforms are correctly extending the sign, then the vendor library cuts it back. In this way, no number out of the signed 32-bit range can appear.. are you sure this is the only point that may cause the overflow?