# Mouse wheel disabled/enabled by Alt key

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a graphics app written in C#/WPF.   Scrolling the Mouse wheel zooms the geometry in and out.

In the XAML I have this . . .

```
  <Canvas Name="ROIcnv" Background ="Transparent" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Margin="250,60,20,180" MouseDown="ROIcnvMouseDown"
            MouseUp="ROIcnvMouseUp" MouseMove="ROIcnvMouseMove" ClipToBounds="True" MouseWheel="ROIcnvMouseWheel"  />
```

The handler looks like this . . .

```
 private void ROIcnvMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        double scaleFactor = 1.0;
        // If the mouse wheel delta is positive, scale up
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            scaleFactor = scaleFactor * 1.1;
        }
        // If the mouse wheel delta is negative, scale down
        if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            scaleFactor = scaleFactor * 0.9;
        }
        _Scale = _Scale * scaleFactor;
        StackTransforms();
    }  // end ROIcnvMouseWheel
```

Everything works fine EXCEPT that tapping the keyboard's <kbd>Alt</kbd> key toggles the reception of the mouse events on and off.  If I set a breakpoint in the debugger in the handler it never gets called if I tap the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key before scrolling.  Tap it again and everything's happy.     This happens on all 3 PC's I've tried it on (all Win 7).  What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Typically in an app the ALT key moves focus to the menu bar (fire up notepad and hit ALT). You sure that's not what's happening?

Comment: My app doesn't have a menu bar -  it's basically a Window with a Grid containing the canvas and a few buttons.   Do you think it's shifting the focus to one of the buttons?  (they don't change appearance)   If so how could I tell and how could I prevent that?

Comment: Yup - that's default behaviour for Alt key. 
You might need to have to hook into the desktop message handler and trap it from there .. been a long time though since I did anything at level, but "ProcessCmdKey" seems to ring a bell.

Comment: @Stuart I don't understand what you mean by "that's" the default behavior.   What is "that"?   Changing focus to a different control?  If so wouldn't that control be specified in the XAML? (and how is that done)

Comment: This may be able to help you. It's a message filter that's started in the form startup (change the Alt+F4 to being only the Alt Key): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898680/how-to-disable-altf4-for-the-application/12899915#12899915

Comment: This is not a Form application - it's WPF - would it still work that way?  (I'm assuming that if a Win32 application has a way of saying "go to the file menu when I tap ALT," there must be a way in XAML to say the same thing in XAML)